# Displaying multiple figures using matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot several figures on matlab using a for loop.
I tried [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433326/how-to-create-a-new-figure-in-matlab):

```
figure;
plot(toDplot)
```

and

```
figure(2);
plot(thing)

figure(3);
plot(something)
```

etc

But in both cases, my first plot is replaced by the next one...

Why is it replacing the first frames?

Comment: so you're using `figure(x)` inside the for-loop? but always with the same number `x`? Use a different number every iteration and it will create a new figure, or use `hold on` behind the plot command, to plot multiple graphs in the same figure.

Comment: I'm using figure(k) (when I loop on k). I also tried with hold on but it plots me the different curbs on the same plot and I want each curb to be plotted on a different figure

Comment: So you end up with lots of empty figures and only one with your plot?

Comment: no actually I end up with one figure only which features the last plot

Comment: If you type in the command window the following: `close all; figure; figure;`, does it create 2 figures?

Comment: How about `figure(1); figure(2);`?  Two figures?

Comment: same. And now, I added the close all before my for loop and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new figures are not taking over as the current figure (`gcf`).

To explicitly specify where a plot will go, you can call it with the syntax `plot(HA,...)`.  From the MATLAB docs:

```
plot(axes_handle,___) plots into the axes specified by axes_handle instead of into the current axes (gca)
```

To use this, you would make a figure and axes, storing their handles, like so:

```
hf = figure;
ha = axes('parent',hf);
plot(ha,x,y)
```

P.S.  I just saw that you got it to work by putting a `close all` before your loop!  I'll keep the answer here for reference since it is a good way to be explicit with your plotting.